# Triggering Webscraping script remotely

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, splinter

I have a python webscraping script using splinter that I want to be able to trigger on a remote machine. I was wondering if there is a way to accomplish this without having to setup the Java Selenium Server. I have verified that the script runs without issue on the host when triggered locally.

```
from splinter import Browser
import time
browser = Browser('firefox', profile=r'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\0r9gezm5.default')
browser.visit('https://confluence.com')
browser.find_by_id('login-link').click()
browser.fill('os_username', 'user')
browser.fill('os_password', 'pass')
browser.find_by_name('login').click()
with open ("C:\Webscraping\Download List\Contacts.txt") as sheet:
for website in sheet:
    browser.visit(website)
    browser.find_by_id('action-menu-link').click()
    browser.find_by_id('action-export-pdf-link').click()
```

When trying to trigger script remotely via command line I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "\\host\c$\Webscraping\Scripts\Contacts.py", line 6, in <module>
        browser = Browser('firefox', profile=r'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\0r9gezm5.default')

    File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\splinter\browser.py", line 63, in Browser
        return driver(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\splinter\driver\webdriver\firefox.py", line 57, in __init__
    timeout=timeout, **kwargs)

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py",
    line 158, in __init__
        keep_alive=True)

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
    line 154, in __init__
        self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
    line 243, in start_session
        response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
    line 312, in execute
        self.error_handler.check_response(response)

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py
    ", line 237, in check_response
        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
        selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: connection reset

cmd exited on ch0pwts01 with error code 1.
```

Comment: Does it work over `rdesktop` seesion? How about ssh?

Comment: Should of specified, script runs fine with triggered when remoted in. Issue arises when triggering from a different machine, i.e remotely. The purpose is to be able to have this script triggered regularly through an application similar to Task Scheduler.